# how to query for multiples rows and parse to json?

Tags: sql, json, parsing, go

I have this code:

```
func GetAll(c *gin.Context) {

var veiculos model.Veiculo

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM vei_veiculo")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("[GetAll] erro ao abrir o query db inteiro")
}
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&veiculos)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[GetAll] erro ao scanear uma linha'")
    }
}
fmt.Println(veiculos)}
```

My struct name is at model.Veiculo and I want to print it all once. It seems there is an error on scan the query rows. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should print your error so you can see exactly what is going wrong, but I will also tell you... Scan is expecting a variable for *each column* that you selected - it will not automagically fill your struct fields. There are libraries that will do this for you, but when using the stdlib, you are best explicitly selecting columns instead of using `*` and then scanning then in the correct order.

Comment: You seem to be retrieving multiple rows and scanning them all into a single struct variable instead of scanning each row into its own struct var and then adding that var into a slice. To retrieve multiple rows you should do something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/iPgrwV1eVn7

Comment: ... here's an updated example from the previous comment that illustrates how you can marshal the result into json: https://play.golang.com/p/sBJjeY3iOzc. Please do note that both of these examples only print the errors, in a real program this function should exit after encountering an error, otherwise it will cause your program to crash.

Comment: @mkopriva, it was stored on `v.id` and `v.name` but not on `data`. The array of veiculos seems to be empty

Comment: @AlexColussi you need to use *exported* fields, ie they need to start with upper case letter because `json.Marshal` ignores *unexported* fields, fields that start with lower case letters. Change `v.id` to `v.Id`, `v.name` to `v.Name`.

Comment: @mkopriva, it is with upper case. The `var veiculos` still is empty, by the way, I am following your example here ( play.golang.com/p/sBJjeY3iOzc)

Comment: @AlexColussi I'm sorry I totaly forgot to append each v to veiculos. Fixed version: https://play.golang.com/p/PmAI_0NNDQQ

Comment: @mkopriva thank you a lot man. it works!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `database/sql`, the function signature is `func (rs *Rows) Scan(dest ...interface{}) error`.

You need to be doing scanning into each member of the struct, something more like:

```
err := rows.Scan(&veiculos.ID, &veiculos.Name, &veiculos.Description)
```

Comment: I'm trying to read all and print all.With another package i found a way but I'll have to use the `database/sql`
 there is a way to do that,  there isn't?

Answer (score 0):

To scan each row to its own struct, I recommend an approach like so:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Person struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    Email     string
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "dsn...")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    people := []Person{}

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM people")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        person := Person{}
        if err := rows.Scan(&person.FirstName, &person.LastName, &person.Email); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        people = append(people, person)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", people)
}
```

Alternatively, the library https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx exists as one of the solutions to marshaling SQL query data to structs. I personally prefer this method, as it behaves more like an `Unmarshal` function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

type Person struct {
    FirstName string `db:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `db:"last_name"`
    Email     string `db:"email"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "dsn...")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    people := []Person{}

    if err := db.Select(&people, "SELECT * FROM people"); err != nil {
        log.Fataln(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", people)
}
```

Following either of these approaches allows you to easily use the `json.Marshal`
method with the `people` variable, and viola!

Good luck!